# Why is my update query OK for the database but the page shows the wrong value?

Tags: 8, entities

I have 2 custom content entities created with Drupal Console (drupal generate:entity:content): 'person' and 'member'.
They are linked (1 member <-> n persons) by a field named 'member_id' in 'person'.
If a person is set with 'iscontact' = true, the other persons related to the same member should have 'iscontact' = false.

In the PersonForm.php, I have this code.

```
public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $entity = $this->entity;

  if ($entity->get('iscontact')) {

    $member_id = $entity->get('member_id')->getString();
    $iId = $entity->get('id')->getString();
    $database = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $database->select('person', 'ap');
    $query->fields('ap', ['id', 'member_id'])
      ->condition('id', $iId, '<>')
      ->condition('member_id', $member_id, '=');
    $results = $query->execute();

    foreach ($results as $key=>$result) {
      $numberofrowsaffected = $database->update('person')
        ->fields(['iscontact' => 0,])
        ->condition('id', $result->id)
        ->execute();
    }
  }

  $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);

  switch ($status) {
    case SAVED_NEW:
      drupal_set_message($this->t('La personne « %label » a été ajoutée.', [
        '%label' => $entity->label(),
      ]));
      break;
    default:
      drupal_set_message($this->t('La personne « %label » a été modifiée.', [
        '%label' => $entity->label(),
      ]));
  }
  $form_state->setRedirect('entity.person.canonical', ['person' => $entity->id()]);
}
```

When I execute this, the table 'person' in the database is correctly updated, but in the page the previous person is still seen as having 'iscontact' = 1.
It's incorrect until I clear the cache. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not using the entity API, specifically the storage handler to load and save entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced

```
foreach ($results as $key=>$result) {
  $numberofrowsaffected = $database->update('person')
    ->fields(['iscontact' => 0,])
    ->condition('id', $result->id)
    ->execute();
}
```

by

```
  $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('person');
  foreach ($results as $key=>$result) {
    $person = $storage->load($result->id);
    $person->iscontact = 0;
    $person->save();
```

And it works!